# Best option to edit CSS file on-the-fly under MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have an application that in the admin area there is options such as

```
Background image: [ File Upload ]
Top Illustration: [ File Upload ]
```

and in the front end I want to easily attach this info to the CSS, maybe teh simply way should be

```
.background {
    background: url(<%: Model.BackgroundUrl %>);
    ...
}
```

I currently have my Css files unde `~/Content/Css`

shall I have a View with this and change the content type so I can use the Model part?

What other techniques are available or this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a new View and set all up as:

in the **Master Template**

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content(
                      String.Format("~/{0}/Css/CustomCss.aspx", 
                      ViewData["CalendarUrl"])) %>" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in the **Routes**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CustomCss", // Route name
    "{calurl}/Css/CustomCss.aspx", // URL with parameters
    new { calurl = "none", controller = "Content", action = "CustomCss", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

in the Controller: **Content**, Action: **CustomCss**

```
// GET: /Css/CustomCss
public ActionResult CustomCss(string calurl)
{
    return View();
}
```

in my **View** (placed in **Shared**):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" 
         ContentType="text/css" %>
<%
    string company_logo = ViewData["CompanyLogo"] as string;
    string company_bkg = ViewData["CompanyBackground"] as string;
%>
.background {
<%if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(company_bkg))
  { %>background-image:url('<%: company_bkg %>');<%} %>
}
#header-content{
<%if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(company_logo ))
  { %>background-image:url('<%: company_logo %>');<%} %>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the model in a static CSS file. If you want to achieve this you will need to generate it dynamically using a controller action. As an alternative you could directly use an `img` tag:

```
<img src="<%: Model.BackgroundUrl %>" alt="" />
```

Comment: can't be like that, needs to be, at least `<div class="backgroud" style="background-image: url(<%: Model.BackgroundUrl%>);">`. I was thinking like old ASP days that we had `cssfile.aspx` and we says in page directive that was a css, and all worked fine.